# New usage for the particle に

Tags: grammar, particles

I was talking to my friend, and she said

> きれいにとれた！

What does `に` after an adjective mean, or what does `に` before a verb mean?
And where can I read more about this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, doesn't に just make きれい (a な adjective) an adverb?

> きれいにとれた
>   You were able to take it beautifully.

Comment: Are you asking another question as an answer?

Comment: You are bringing English grammar into Japanese.  In Japanese, no matter how you conjugate an adjective, it still remains an adjective as a part of speech.

Comment: @l'électeur Very interesting.  I'm by no means a competent speaker of Japanese and I only answered this question because I was pretty sure I understood the sentence.  You don't by any chance know of any source where I could read about Japanese grammar from a Japanese point of view without imposing English convention (written in English)?  I feel such a perspective would greatly aid my study.  Thanks!

Comment: @G-Cam The きれいに adjectivally modifies the verb 取れた, but きれいに is not an adverb but the ren'yo-kei (continuative form) of the na-adjective きれいな. (Have you learnt "ren'yo-kei"?)

Comment: @choco I've learned of the 連用形 in the context of verbs and verbal adjectives but not with regard to na-adjectives.  My understanding was that it could be used to create compound verbs, connect sentences in a way similar to the te-form, or stand alone as a noun. So, in a phrase like "食べ過ぎる", is 食べ still considered a verb that "verbally" modifies 過ぎる? Thanks